# How to draw the following diagram with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote, metapost

I want to draw the following diagram 
[image]

Where $BE$ is a tangent at $B$. Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4.0, axes/.style={thick,->}]
    \draw[axes] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[axes] (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2) node[above] {$y$};

    \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1];

    \draw[->] (0.2,0) node[above right]{$\theta$} arc[start angle=0, end angle=30, radius=0.2];
    \draw (0,0) -- node[below]{$\cos \theta$} ({sqrt(3)/2},0)
        -- node[right,fill=white]{\ \ $\theta$} ({sqrt(3)/2},0.5)
        -- cycle;
    \path (0,0) -- node[above]{$1$} ({sqrt(3)/2},0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: (Thanks to [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/989637?noredirect=1)) BD an extension of OB, and is AD supposed to be vertical.

Comment: Is BD an extension of OB, and is AD supposed to be vertical?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That's right, "BD an extension of OB, and is AD supposed to be vertical." Sorry for my bad drawing. I will edit that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit crude, but given the angle `a`, the required point `E` is at 
`(1,(1-cos(a))/sin(a))` or `(1,cosec(a)-cot(a))`

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=4cm, y=4cm, axes/.style={thin, gray, ->},
  dot/.style={.. dot={#1:0:;}}, 
  .. dot/.style args={#1:#2:#3;}{insert path={ 
    coordinate (#1) 
    node [circle, fill, inner sep=0, minimum size=2pt,label=#2:#1]{}
  }}]
\clip (-0.25, -0.25) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
\draw[axes] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[axes] (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2) node[above] {$y$};
\def\a{40}
\path
  (0,0)  [dot=O:225] 
  (0:1)  [dot=A:315]
  (\a:1) [dot=B:90]  
  (0:cos \a) [dot=C:270]
  (\a:sec \a) [dot=D]
  (1, cosec \a-cot \a) [dot=E];
\draw (O) circle[radius=1];
\draw (O) -- (B) -- (C);
\draw (B) -- (D) -- (A);
\draw [dashed] (B) -- (A);
\draw [dashed] (B) -- (E);
\pic ["$\theta$", draw, ->, angle radius=1cm] {angle=C--O--B};
\path (O) -- (B) node [midway, above] {$1$};
\path (O) -- (C) node [midway, below] {$\cos\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how do you put $\theta$ on the arc in your case?

Comment: @marya if you mean the arc on the unit circle, I wouldn't put `$\theta$` there (a) because it is too 'crowded' and with or without a white background may obscure one or more of  the lines BA, BE or ED, and (b) it is unnecessary given the annotation near the origin.

Comment: Nice point. But what if I wanted the $\theta$ on the arc. How different would it be? Could you show me?

Comment: @marya you could try `\node [fill=white] at (\a/2:1) {$\theta$};`, probably adjusting the inner sep of the node if necessary.

Comment: Worked Perfectly. Gracias!

Answer (score 7):

Also available in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html)...

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    path xx, yy, circle;
    pair O, A, B, C, D, E;
    numeric theta;

    xx = (6 left -- 6 right) scaled 1cm;
    yy = (1 down -- 6 up) scaled 1cm;
    circle = fullcircle scaled 10cm;

    theta = 42;

    O = origin;
    A = point 0 of circle;
    B = point theta * 8 / 360 of circle;
    C = (xpart B, 0);
    D = whatever[O,B]; D-A = whatever * up;
    E = whatever[A,D]; B-E = whatever * (B-O) rotated 90;

    drawarrow xx withpen pencircle scaled .8;
    drawarrow yy withpen pencircle scaled .8;
    draw subpath (-1/4, 17/4) of circle withcolor .67 red;

    draw E--B dashed evenly scaled 1/2 withcolor .75 blue;
    draw A--B dashed evenly scaled 1/2 withcolor .75 blue;

    draw A--D--O;
    draw C--B;

    label.rt  ("$x$", point 1 of xx);
    label.top ("$y$", point 1 of yy);

    label.llft("$\scriptstyle O$", O);
    label.lrt ("$\scriptstyle A$", A);
    label.top ("$\scriptstyle B$", B + 3 up);
    label.bot ("$\scriptstyle C$", C);
    label.top ("$\scriptstyle D$", D);
    label.rt  ("$\scriptstyle E$", E);

    label.ulft("$1$", 1/2 B);
    label.bot("$\cos\theta$", 1/2 C);

    path a; a = fullcircle scaled 42 cutafter (O--B);
    interim ahangle := 25; 
    drawarrow a withcolor .5 white;
    label.rt("$\theta$", point .5 of a);

    picture t;
    t = thelabel("$\theta$", point 1/2 theta * 8 / 360 of circle);
    unfill bbox t; draw t;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

- `left`, `right`, `up`, and `down` are defined in plain MP to be the pairs `(-1,0)`, `(1,0)`, `(0,1)`, and `(0,-1)`.  So they are convenient for describing 
  the axes, as variations on the path `left -- right`.   I could have written: `xx = (-6cm,0) -- (6cm,0);` instead, but I like using the names instead of the numbers.
- `fullcircle` is also defined in plain MP, to be a circle with unit *diameter*, so to get a circle with a 5cm radius, I have defined `fullcircle scaled 10cm`.
- `fullcircle` is defined in plain MP to have 8 "points" starting at 3 o'clock (as it were) and going round counter clockwise, so that 12 o'clock is point 2, and 6 o'clock is point 6, and so on.  The construction `point theta / 8 * 360 of circle` gives the point that is `theta` degrees counter clockwise from point 0.

Comment: It is always a pleasure to read your Metapost answers! One small criticism: IMHO, a beginner will have a hard time understanding  `point theta * 8 / 360 of circle` because `8` appears to be a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants). I think that `point theta / 360 along circle` is easier to understand, but that would require adding `metafun` as a dependency.

Comment: @Aditya thank you!  I never can quite decide if I want to add lots of explanatory notes, or allow readers to puzzle it out for themselves.  But I think that here, you are right, and I should add a note.

Comment: Actually, in this case `B = 5cm * dir theta;` might be easier!

Comment: True.  But then we would need to make the radius a variable, to keep with the principle of orthogonality that I like to follow.

Answer (score 6):

`Asymptote` `MWE`:

```
//
// theta.asy
//
// To get theta.pdf, run 
//
// asy theta.asy
//

settings.tex="pdflatex";
import graph;
size(5cm);
import fontsize;defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}"
+"\usepackage{amsmath}"
+"\usepackage{amsfonts}"
+"\usepackage{amssymb}"
);

real w=0.5bp;
pen linePen=darkblue+w;
pen arcPen=orange+w;
pen markPen=gray(0.3)+w;
pen axisPen=gray(0.3)+w;
pen dashPen=gray(0.3)+w+linetype(new real[]{5,5})+squarecap;
arrowbar arr=Arrow(HookHead,size=2);

xaxis("$x$",0,1.1,axisPen,arr);
yaxis("$y$",0,1.1,axisPen,arr);

real R=1,theta=42;
pair O,A,B,C,D,E;

guide gc=Arc(O,R,-4,94);
A=(R,0); B=rotate(theta)*A; C=(B.x,0);
D=extension(O,B,A,A+(0,1));
E=extension(A,D,B,B+rotate(90)*(B-O));
draw(gc,arcPen);
draw(B--C^^O--D--A,linePen);
draw(A--B--E,dashPen);

pair[] p={O,A,B,C,D,E};
string[] lab={"O","A","B","C","D","E"};
pair[] dp={plain.SW,plain.SW,plain.N,plain.S,plain.N,plain.E,};
for(int i=0;i<p.length;++i){
    dot(p[i],UnFill);
    label(lab[i],p[i],dp[i]);
}

draw("$\theta$",arc(O,0.12,0,theta),markPen);
label("$1$",(O+B)/2,UnFill);
label("$\cos\theta$",(O+C)/2,UnFill);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The point `D` is at (R,R*tan(theta)), `E` is found by the help of the `intersections` library. I modified some other things as well, such as declaring constants used for angle and radius, and drawing the various elements based on those. There are a now some comments in the code.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
%  scale=4.0,
  axes/.style={thick,->},
  declare function={
    % define functions/constants for angle and radius
    theta=30; 
    R=4;
  },
  % reduce font size for labels
  every label/.append style={font=\scriptsize}
]
    % addition: base axes length on radius
    \draw[axes] (-1.2*R,0) -- (1.2*R,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[axes] (0,-1.2*R) -- (0,1.2*R) node[above] {$y$};

    % addition: add named coordinate with label in origin
    % use constant defined above for radius
    \draw (0,0) coordinate[label=below left:$O$] (O) circle[radius=R];

    % addition: start point of arc relative to radius
    \draw[->] (0.2*R,0) node[above right]{$\theta$} arc[start angle=0, end angle=theta, radius=0.2*R];

    % additions;
    %  - named coordinates with labels in B and C
    %  - moved drawing of "1" node to this path (no need for a second one I think)
    \draw (O) -- node[below]{$\cos \theta$} ({R*cos(theta)},0) coordinate [label=below:$C$] (C)
        -- ({R*cos(theta)},{R*sin(theta)}) coordinate[label=above:$B$] (B)
        -- node[above]{$1$} cycle;

    % new path, drawing from A via D to B
    % name this path A, to use later
    \draw [name path=A] (R,0) coordinate[label=below right:$A$] (A)
        -- (R,{R*tan(theta)}) coordinate [label=above right:$D$] (D)
        -- (B);

    % path that doesn't influence bounding box (overlay option)
    % starting at B, using polar coordinates to make the path tangent
    % to the circle
    % name path B to use below
    \path[overlay,name path=B] (B) -- ++(theta-90:R);

    % calculate intersections of ADB path and the invisible path, name the first
    % intersection E. draw dasdhed line from B to E
    \draw [name intersections={of=A and B,by={E,}},dashed] (B) -- (E) node[right,font=\scriptsize] {$E$};


    \draw [dashed] (B) -- (A);

    % alternative way of placing second theta-node, saves manual adjustment
    % relative to the line BC
    \path (A) arc[start angle=0,end angle=theta/2,radius=R] node[inner sep=1pt,fill=white]{$\theta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```